# Loading decrypted Password with Jasypt in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, encryption, jasypt

I'm trying to setup the Jasypt workflow with Spring Boot. As described in [this Tutorial](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot#what-to-do-first), I added the required dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Encrypted the password with:

```
mvn jasypt:encrypt-value -Djasypt.encryptor.password=javatechie -Djasypt.plugin.value=Password
```

Created an `encrypted.properties` and put the encrypted password inside:

```
secret.property=ENC(nrmZtkF7T0kjG/VodDvBw93Ct8EgjCAaskygdq8PHapYFnlX6WsTwZZOxWInq+i)
```

Annotated my Main Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEncryptableProperties
@PropertySource(name = "EncryptedProperties", value = "classpath:encrypted.properties")
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

In another class I try to load the decrypted value:

```
@Component
public class MyOtherClass {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyOtherClass.class);

    @Value("${secret.property}")
    String secret;

    public MyOtherClass() {
        LOGGER.info("PW: " + secret);
    }
}
```

But I just get:

```
PW: null
```

---

When I change the value into something nonexistent:

```
@Value("${abc.def}")
String secret;
```

I get the expected error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'abc.def' in value "${abc.def}"

So it seems to find my actual value `secret.property`, but why it's `null`?

Comment: Can you make sure that your `encrypted.properties` file is loaded properly? I mean I can not see any @Configuration with `@PropertySource(name = "EncryptedProperties", value = "classpath:encrypted.properties")`. Try to put some dummy key-value and get it inside your component.

Comment: Check the logs for any Jasypt Exception.

Comment: @sushant: In the logs it says: `o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'secret.property' in PropertySource 'environmentProperties' with value of type String`. But still the value is `null`.

Comment: @KumarAshutosh: The `@PropertySource(name = "EncryptedProperties", value = "classpath:encrypted.properties")` is in my `Main.class`.

Comment: You are accessing injected property in a bean. Spring instantiates the bean first and then injects the values. You can try accessing the value outside of the constructor, say a bean method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the injected property in the constructor. This does not work because here Spring will instantiate the bean, and then inject the property. So, if you access the property in the constructor you will get the default value before the injection which is `null`. If you want to access the property in the constructor, then you can use constructor injection like so:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyOtherClass {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = 
                      LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyOtherClass.class);

    String secret;

    @Autowired
    public MyOtherClass(@Value("${secret.property}") String secret) {
        LOGGER.info("PW: " + secret);
        this.secret = secret;
    }
}
```